# Flutter: Stream<Null> is allowed?

Tags: null, stream, flutter, sink

Sometimes, when I´m watching some projects that work with streams, I see something like:

```
final controller = StreamController<Null>();
```

and then:

```
controller.sink.add(null);
```

So, is allowed to pass *null* in streams? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Null` as generic type argument was used before `void` was supported and means in this case that only the occurence of the even is meaningful, but the event value is not.

With `Null` the value `null` is the only valid event value. With `void` a callback function can be passed that does not take any parameter.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hack around the fact that sinks require an argument.

Some peoples use streams as a flux of events instead of a value changing over time, but the class isn't designed with this in mind. They typically try to represent the following method as a stream:

```
void onClick();
```

Comment: So, basically it´s allowed, even if streams are not designed to be used like this.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement flux of events?